# Animation not rendering assigned materials

Tags: rendering, animation, materials

I'm very new to blender and have been building my first project of a toaster with toast. However, when I render the image, for some reason the final result never renders the materials assigned to the objects. I've read some of the other threads that had similar issues and I've checked the following:

- There was no materials override
- In the image viewer, it is in alpha and color mode

Below is the image viewer when I open render image, and the materials tab for the toaster as an example.

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/